# Can't find stored procedure for updating after creating it

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure to update my table

```
create proc UPDATE_PRODUCT
@ID_CAT INT,
@ID_PRODUCT VARCHAR(30),
@LABEL NVARCHAR(30),
@QTE INT,
@PRICE VARCHAR(50),
@IMG IMAGE
AS
UPDATE [Product_DB].[dbo].[PRODUCTS]
   SET [ID_CAT] = @ID_CAT
      ,[LABEL_PRODUCT] = @LABEL
      ,[QTE_IN_STOCK] = @QTE
      ,[PRICE] = @PRICE
      ,[IMAGE_PRODUCT] = @IMG
 WHERE ID_PRODUCT = @ID_PRODUCT
```

When I run this code the first time, it says "completed successfully"
However, I can't find it in Stored Procedure folder. I tried to do multiple refreshes and restarts but still the same.

When I try to create a procedure for other purpose like selecting or deleting, it works with no problems.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is ***typically*** because you were in the wrong database context (in this sense, "wrong" means really "unexpected".

In other words, you were expecting to create the stored procedure in `Database1`, but you were really in the context of `Database2`.

This is the exactly reason why I'm always explicit, especially with DDL.  At the top of your script/query window/etc., always put:

```
use YourDatabase;
go
```

This will ensure you don't run into this snag again.  I tend to not rely on GUI drop-down lists and my memory to double-check which database is selected before running management SQL queries.